# Inner class of template class will not compile on XCode 4.5.2

Tags: c++, xcode, templates, stl, iterator

In XCode 4.5.2 the class `Proxy` as defined below does not compile.  I can give more details about the specific compiler if necessary, although it should be the default as I have not changed anything in the XCode configuration.  It compiles in VStudio Express.

```
#include <list>
#include <boost/thread/tss.hpp>

template <typename T>
class Cache
{
public:
    class Proxy : public T
    {
        friend class Cache;

    private:
        std::list<Proxy> & m_refList;
        typename std::list<Proxy>::iterator m_clsPosition;

        Proxy(std::list<Proxy> & refList) : m_refList(refList) {}
    };

private:
    std::list<Proxy> m_clsList;
    typename std::list<Proxy>::iterator m_clsCurrent;

    static void Release(Proxy * ptrProxy)
    {
        ptrProxy->m_refList.splice(ptrProxy->m_refList.m_clsCurrent,
                                   ptrProxy->m_refList,
                                   ptrProxy->m_clsPosition);
        if ( ptrProxy->m_refList.m_clsCurrent == ptrProxy->m_refList.end() )
            --(ptrProxy->m_refList.m_clsCurrent);
    }

public:
    Cache() {m_clsCurrent = m_clsList.end();}
    ~Cache()
    {
        if ( m_clsList.size() && m_clsCurrent != m_clsList.begin() )
        {
            // ERROR - Cache not empty
        }
    }

    typedef boost::shared_ptr<Proxy> Ptr;

    static Ptr Get()
    {
        static boost::thread_specific_ptr<Cache> clsCache;
        if ( clsCache.get() == NULL )
            clsCache.reset(new Cache());

        Proxy * ptrProxy;
        if ( clsCache->m_clsCurrent == clsCache->m_clsList.end() )
        {
            clsCache->m_clsList.push_front(Proxy(clsCache->m_clsList));
            ptrProxy = &(clsCache->m_clsList.front());
            ptrProxy->m_clsPosition = clsCache->m_clsList.begin();
        }
        else
        {
            ptrProxy = &(*(clsCache->m_clsCurrent));
            ptrProxy->m_clsPosition = clsCache->m_clsCurrent++;
        }
        return Ptr(ptrProxy, Release);
    }
};
```

The compilation error is on the line `typename std::list<Proxy>::iterator m_clsPosition`:

```
No type named 'iterator' in 'std::__1::list<ASW::Cache<std::__1::basic_string<char>>::Proxy, std::__1::allocator<ASW::Cache<std::__1::basic_string<char>>::Proxy>>'
```

(the template parameter to Cache is `std::basic_string<char>`)

I understand what's happening - I'm referencing `Proxy` before it's fully defined.  But why does `iterator` need the definition of `Proxy` to compile?

The reason for the data structure is two-fold: 1) to reclaim objects instead of destroying them, and 2) to expedite reclamation by keeping an iterator in the cached object to its position in the list.  If anyone has a better idea of how to implement these (providing this error can't be fixed), I'd be interested to hear of it.

Comment: As you can see from the other comments, it's due to a limitation of the standard.  I briefly looked into `boost::container::list` and that would have been viable as it is designed to contain incomplete types; I also looked at `boost::ptr_list`, but the runtime is not O(1) for moving a node in the list.  I ended up rolling my own, which I hate to do for common tasks like this.  I'll post the code after I've tested it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has undefined behaviour because you are instantiating `std::list` with an incomplete type (`Proxy` is not yet defined within its definition). `[res.on.functions]/2`:

> ... the effects are undefined ... if an incomplete type is used as a template argument when instantiating a template component, unless specifically allowed for that component.

Try using an implementation of `list` that [works with incomplete types](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/container/containers_of_incomplete_types.html), such as [boost::container::list](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_container_header_reference.html#header.boost.container.list_hpp).

Comment: I was afraid it was something like this.  I'm not instantiating `std::list<Proxy>` but `std::list<Proxy>::iterator`.  Why does the compiler have to be able to compile all of `std::list<Proxy>` just to compile `std::list<Proxy>::iterator`, and that being the case, why does the standard require such a thing?  Not that I mind using boost libraries, I just prefer the simplest, most common class available as a first resort.

Comment: @jorgander: Using `std::list<Proxy>::iterator` implies an instantiation of `std::list<Proxy>` (otherwise where would the `iterator` typedef be defined?). As far as I know, there is no good reason for the standard giving this undefined behaviour (other than a lack of time on the part of the committee and/or a lack of relevant proposals).

Comment: I'm sure the standards committee had their reasons, but I don't see how inner class instantiation requires outer class instantiation.  A compiler can be aware of the structure of a template before any template parameter is passed (e.g. when first parsed in the source code) and only compile/instantiate what is necessary.  Generally MS is wrong to circumvent the standard, but I think they decided correctly about this one.

Anyway, it is what it is.  Thank you for confirming my suspicion.